# Склонение сложного существительного — названия ("Сапфир-концерн")

Tags: склонение, орфография

Нужно ли склонять обе части сложного названия, если оно употребляется без родового слова? Например, "Сапфир-концерн". Гендиректор "Сапфира-концерна" или гендиректор "Сапфир-концерна"?

Comment: Кстати, "обе" в винительном и родительном падежах имеет форму "об**е**их", а не "обоих".  В дательном - "обеим", и т.д.

Comment: В винительном падеже возможны формы "обе" и "обеих".

Comment: Согласен.  Но в родительном не "обоих" всё-таки...

Comment: в заге - да, спасибо, а то я никак не пойму, где вы слово "обоих" увидели)))

Comment: а на вопрос можете ответить?

Comment: С уверенностью не могу.  Информация по составным существительным (см. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/63-rubric-93) подсказывает, что нет, склонять "Сапфир" не следует.

Comment: А слово "обоих" у Вас в заголовке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно склонять обе части. "Сапфир" остаётся без изменений, см. Письмовник.

[Как склонять составные существительные?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/63-rubric-93)

Там нет примера с именем собственным, но его можно приравнять к определению, это пункт 1.2(2).

Или - ориентироваться на [ведущее слово](http://bibliotekar.ru/deloproizvodstvo-1/67.htm), а в нашем случае это концерн.

> Если ведущим является второе слово («Роман-газета» — издание,
>   публикующее романы), то склоняется только вторая часть: Про­читать в
>   «Роман-газете».

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!

Comment: Нет чтобы лайкнуть! )))

Comment: Извините, я честно пыталась, не могла разобраться, куда нажать, чтобы лайкнуть. Я здесь новичок. Теперь вроде исправилась? =)